# Feign jackson dateTime JsonMappingException

Tags: kotlin, jackson, feign

I've got two services that are communicating with openfeign (github.openfeign:10.2.0). I'm forcing problem with deserializing datatime that is sent as JSON.
Here is my configuration:

```
@Configuration
class JacksonConfig : WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
    override fun extendMessageConverters(converters: List<HttpMessageConverter<*>>?) {
        for (converter in converters!!) {
            if (converter is MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter) {
                val objectMapper = converter.objectMapper
                objectMapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS)
                objectMapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DURATIONS_AS_TIMESTAMPS)
                break
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
    private val client = Feign.builder()
        .encoder(JacksonEncoder())
        .decoder(JacksonDecoder())
        .target(Client::class.java, host)
```

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
data class XYZ(
  var id: Int? = null,
  val X: Int? = null,
  val Y: Int? = null,
  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
  val z: Type? = null,
  @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")
  val createdOn: LocalDateTime? = null
)
```

Here is exception:

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is feign.FeignException: Can not construct instance of java.time.LocalDateTime: no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('2019-03-06T16:50:53')
  at [Source: java.io.BufferedReader@3c14b300; line: 1, column: 77] (through reference chain: java.util.HashSet[0]->XYZ["createdOn"]) reading GET http://localhost:8080/path] with root cause 
  com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of java.time.LocalDateTime: no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('2019-03-06T16:50:53')
  at [Source: java.io.BufferedReader@3c14b300; line: 1, column: 77] (through reference chain: java.util.HashSet[0]->XYZ["createdOn"])
```

Here is Json:

```
[
  {
    "id": 2,
    "X": 1,
    "U": 1,
    "Z": "ABC",
    "createdOn": "2019-03-06T16:50:53"
  }
]
```

Dependencies:

```
    compile group: 'io.github.openfeign', name: 'feign-core', version: '10.2.0'
    compile group: 'io.github.openfeign', name: 'feign-jackson', version: '10.2.0'
    compile "com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk:$jackson_version"
    compile "com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:$jackson_version"
    compile "com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin:$jackson_config"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When we take a look how [`JacksonEncoder`](https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign/blob/master/jackson/src/main/java/feign/jackson/JacksonEncoder.java) and [`JacksonDecoder`](https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign/blob/master/jackson/src/main/java/feign/jackson/JacksonDecoder.java) are implemented we will notice they create new `ObjectMapper` in constructor:

```
public JacksonDecoder(Iterable<Module> modules) {
  this(new ObjectMapper().configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)
      .registerModules(modules));
}
```

Above constructor is invoked by default with `emptyList()`. So, we need to provide all modules we want to use manually.

To get the most from `Java 8` and `Jackson` register all 3 modules from [jackson-modules-java8](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8):

```
private val client = Feign.builder()
    .encoder(JacksonEncoder(Arrays.asList(JavaTimeModule(), ...)))
    .decoder(JacksonDecoder(Arrays.asList(JavaTimeModule(), ...)))
    .target(Client::class.java, host)
```

**EDIT**
Ther is a constructor which allow to use `ObjectMapper` instance. You can create new instance or inject from your container:

```
val mapper = ObjectMapper()
mapper.registerModule(ParameterNamesModule())
   .registerModule(Jdk8Module())
   .registerModule(JavaTimeModule())
// other configuration

val client = Feign.builder()
    .encoder(JacksonEncoder(mapper))
    .decoder(JacksonDecoder(mapper))
    .target(Client::class.java, host)
```

Comment: Ok I've added it but as I can see in debug mode during JacksonDecoder initialization there is no JavaTimeModule. Moreover @Configuration JacksonConfig is executed after JsonDecoder() in feign.

Comment: @MrNetroful, Probably `ObjectMapper` from `JacksonConfig` is not used by `JacksonDecoder`. See my answer after update.

Comment: Thank you very much it's solving my problem. I though that JacksonDecoder is somehow injecting existing mapper.

Comment: @MrNetroful, it looks like they do not use it. Even more `Decoder` and `Encoder` also have it's own `ObjectMapper` so provide same list to both. I will update my answer.

Comment: I can use existing objectMapper by injecting with autowired.

Comment: @MrNetroful, There is a constructor which allow to provide instance of `ObjectMapper` so you need to use it. In `Spring` or whatever you use you need to get and inject `ObjectMapper` from `JacksonConfig`.